# How to Sort UIDocuments with respect to date inside it?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, xcode4.5, xcode4.6

I have to tried to sort using date only after getting the documents after the query returns documents. Is it Possible to Sort UIDocuments with respect to date (User data) inside it when i make a query.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340239/how-can-i-sort-an-icloud-nsmetadataquery-result-of-uidocuments-by-modification

Comment: yes, I saw it ,but the solution is for NSMetadataItemFSContentChangeDateKey which is not the custom date which i have inside my document which can be changed by the user.